# Setting ComboBox RowSource property to query in "GotFocus()" method leaves blank values in ComboBox Access VBA

Tags: vba, combobox

I want to populate my ComboBox in an Access form using VBA based on data from another table. Previously to do this I did the following:

- In the Property Sheet -> Data tab I filled out Row Source and Row Source Type fields with this information:

[image]

Now whenever I clicked on the dropdown for my combobox, it would populate the dropdown list with all of the names from t_people table.

This limited me however to when data changed in the t_people's name column. In order to get an updated list, I must close the form and re-open it so that the query runs again. I have limited the access to this Access file so that the user is only presented with x number of forms, and cannot close/open them or others.

My solution is to remove the query on the form load, and instead run the query every time the combobox gains focus, has a click event or something of the same sorts. I did this with the following event in VBA:

```
'Run when the "name" combobox gains focus
Private Sub nameCb_GotFocus()
    [nameCb].RowSource = "SELECT name FROM t_people"
End Sub
```

I have set breakpoints and this code does run. However, the the combobox is not populated after it does. How can I get the combobox to populate with the values from a query for each time the combobox gains focus?

Comment: You can put it back to where it was (through the form property) and add `.Requery` but on `Enter()` event.

Comment: Can you make that an answer so I can accept it? It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the RowSource in design and add a `.Requery` when entering the control.

```
Private Sub nameCb_Enter()
    nameCb.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why doesn't my attempted solution work since the code does run every time.

Comment: It's kind of a mystery really. First of all Enter fires before the GotFocus, that's easy to test. In addition I believe you need to Requery in order to update the rowsource of the control. Requery rebuilds the rowsource from scratch but setting the rowsource as in your example, does not necessarily means it will be rebuilt. That's my understanding. But I've seen cases where you need to set the rousource of the control again in order to update: `o.RowSource = o.RowSource`. Maybe some of the more experienced members can shed some light.